# Lemma about Dedekind ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I think it will be obvious for some people but I started reading Algebraic Number Theory of A. Frolich & J.W.S Cassels and I don't understand the proof of a lemma.
If we take $R$ a Dedekind ring, $K=\operatorname{Frac}(R)$, $U$ a vector space of finite dimension over $K$ and $T$ a $R$-submodule of $U$ then the lemma says that $$\bigcap_p T_p =T$$
where $p$ are prime ideals of R, $T_p=TR_p$ where $R_p=(R\setminus p)^{-1}R$.
And in the book it is said that this is clear that : $$T \subset \cap_p T_p$$

I don't understand why :/.

Comment: What is $\;T\;$ ??

Comment: oh sorry, it is a $R$-submodule of $U$

Comment: Then please do add that info to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $R$ is an integral domain, we have $R \subset R_p$ when we consider both as subsets of $K$. (Because elements of $R_p$ are of the form $\frac{r}{s}$ with $r \in R$ and $s \in R\setminus P$, and we can always set $s=1$, to get $R \ni r=\frac{r}{1} \in R_p)$

Then $T=TR \subset TR_p=T_p$, where the first equality holds because $T$ is an $R$-module. Because this holds for any $p$, we have $T \subset \cap_p T_p$

Comment: oh thanks !! that's clear, it was obvious. I didn't see it :/ I was confused by all the structure that appear in this chapter of the book.

Comment: just, why do you need that $R$ is integral ?

Comment: @Pierre21 for two things: First, it doesn't make sense to consider $R$ or $R_p$ as a subset $K$ (which doesn't make sense, we can fix that a bit by localizating only at non-zerodivisors, but that's not important here). Mainly I wrote that because the homomorphism $R \to R_p$ doesn't have to be injective when $R$ is not an integral domain, so it would be very wrong to write $R \subset R_p$ in this case. Think about $R= \Bbb Z/(2) \times \Bbb Z/(2)$ and we localize at the ideal generated by $(\overline{1},0)$, the localization is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/(2)$ and the second factor becomes $0$.

Comment: Okay thank you for your time !